# <li> looking bizarre on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I'm getting a little problem with "li" on IE. The "li" are not being displayed as block and the "list-style-image" doesn't work too.
I've looked for whole web and I didn't find something similar.. On FF, Chrome and Safari the result is pretty good..

Thanks for any help. Below, my HTML and IE CSS:

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>IE test</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="content/images/">

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/alerts_rev00.css">
   <!--[if gte IE 7]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/alertsIE_rev00.css" />
   <![endif]--> 

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="error_msg">
     <ul>
      <li>Please, fill the "adress" field.</li>
      <li>Please, chose an username containing 4 character, at least.</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
 <html>

 body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  }

 #error_msg ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 476px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  background-color: #ffeaea;
  list-style-image: url("http://www.dvertr.com/content/images/dvertr_erro_icone.png");
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ef404a;
  color: #ef404a;
  text-align: left;
  }

 #error_msg ul li{
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: georgia, times, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: First thing to try is probably adding a valid DOCTYPE, otherwise IE will be rendering in quirks mode, and that will create all sorts of problems. Also in passing -- be consistent with closing your elements. You've got two unclosed or self-closing `link` elements, and one that's closed. Which isn't an error in certain DOCTYPEs, but is in others...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "list-style-image" will only lead to pain and suffering my friend. Swap it out for a background-image on the LI. ***Much*** easier to render across browsers.

```
li {
   padding: 0 0 0 20px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 2px 2px;
   background-image: url("http://www.dvertr.com/content/images/dvertr_erro_icone.png")
}
```

Change the position to move it around to balance as needed.

Comment: Good ideia Graham! I'll try that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a CSS Reset just in case to standardize your elements like `<li>` and others?

Plus as mentioned by @Matt Gibson, you need to add your `<!DOCTYPE>`

Comment: yes friends, I'm using a css reset by "meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/" and a <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">. I'll try what told me Graham below, but thanks for the <html> unclosed tag tip ;)

Comment: @Rafael Camargo - usually it is best to show unmodified code (html / css) in full context so we do see things like your DOCTYPE or your CSS reset, otherwise you create traps for us that make it hard to accurately answer your question.

Comment: good tip Jakub! The problem with bizarre <li> was already solved, but for the next problems with css on IE (cause I know it will happen), I'll write the complete html code ;) Thanks!